# JSON array into php variable

Tags: php, arrays, json

ARRAY:
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/games?q=League%20of%20Legends&type=suggest

Greetings! I am trying to get a value within an array. What i'm trying to go for is the large box art of a certain game. So how do I do this? Here is my attempt, but I am getting these errors.

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /???/test.php on line 4
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /???/test.php on line 4
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /???/test.php on line 4

```
<?php
$game = urlencode($_GET['game']); // This is "League of Legends" in the URL
$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/games?q={$game}&type=suggest'), true);
echo "IMG: ". $json_array->games[0]->box->large; // line 4
```

Comment: what is the code in your line 4 ?

Comment: yep since PHP is stating the issue is on line 4 and you've only shown 3 lines we have to ask if you can show line 4 in your file :)  I also suggest that you sanitize and ensure that the value of $_GET['game'] is proper.  You can do that in many different ways depending on the content that's required for that variable...  For instance it it's a string validate that it is a string, etc.

Comment: You've passed `true` as the 2nd arg to `json_decode` which forces it to create an associative array instead of an object. You want something like `$json_array['games'][0]['box']['large']`. Or simply don't pass a 2nd arg

Comment: @JosephCrawford `$_GET` values are **always** strings. I'd also say passing it through `urlencode()` is safe enough

Comment: @phil has the answer, it's not an object, hence the error message

Comment: In this case urlencode may be enough but I wanted to get them thinking about sanitization.  If you try to use these in a database query they would be WIDE OPEN to sql injection.  In the case of tacking onto a web service URL I could still cause havok if the web service is not protected from SQL Injection.  The OP could find themselves in trouble if this web service is say for a distributor offering an API to get products.  If they pass through an SQL injection and that service is not protected the distributor wishes to blame them for lost data etc.  I've seen this happen personally.

Comment: @JosephCrawford if OP or said web-service isn't using prepared statements for SQL parameters, then they only have themselves to blame for SQL injection vulnerabilities. The fact that OP actually used `urlencode` tells me that they are already thinking about sanitisation

Comment: You should use double quotes in the `file_get_contents` function, otherwise the `$game` variable is not going to be replaced.

Comment: Phil, i'd like to see you use that excuse when you sign contracts with web services :)  You will surely be at fault as the company I worked for was when another developer didn't sanitize the data.  Just saying that was a hell of a payout to the web service :)  You can say it's their fault all you want it depends on the contract and legal verbiage.  After seeing that happen I have sanitized and cleansed all data from SQL injection whether it was going to my DB or a web service, it;s just good practice and url encode is not enough alone.

Comment: Alvaro good catch, I didn't notice that right away  :)

Comment: This exact script won't be used in any web services. I just need a quick and dirty script to get the idea of what I am trying to achieve. I am well aware of how unsafe the code is if put on a live project. And thank you Alvaro

Comment: what is the output of `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/games?q={$game}&type=suggest` I mean, what is the output of `$game`

Answer (score 1):

You should first get your content. You wasn't get content before. Below line returns `$json_array` correctly.

```
$json_array=json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/games?q='.$game.'&type=suggest'), true);
```

Then edit your second line like below

```
echo "IMG: ". $json_array['games'][0]['box']['large'];
```

## So your final and working code like this:

```
$game = urlencode($_GET['game']); // This is "League of Legends" in the URL
$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/games?q='.$game.'&type=suggest'), true);

echo "IMG: ". $json_array['games'][0]['box']['large'];
```

It absolutely works, I tried and get

```
IMG: http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/League%20of%20Legends-272x380.jpg
```

as output

Answer (score 0):

This error simply says that $json_array is an array not an object. You have to access object element with -> and array elements with [].
If $json_array is array then you have to access it's elements with

```
$json_array['games']
```

And if $json_array is object then you have to access it's elements with

```
  $json_array->games
```